# textContent not working in IE. Need a generic code sample

Tags: jquery, html, flexigrid

```
parentId=$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth(6)')[0].textContent;
```

I am trying to get ID from flexigrid column. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but it throws error in IE-  **'closest(...).find(...).0.textContent' is null or not an object**.

Is there any substitute for textContent in IE? Or is there a way to make it generic to work in all the browsers?

PS: Am using IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for jQuery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)?

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth(6)').text()
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But is there a way to make IE support textContent by modifying Jquery or adding some code?

Comment: that's already the solution, why make it complicated? most likely, jQuery's uses `textContent` for other browsers, and `innerText` for IE, and wrapped into a function called `.text()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent

Comment: You could try textContent first, then use innerText for browsers that don't do textContent...  `elem.textContent || elem.innerText` or more elaborate, see bottom of this post: http://www.vladisan.com/innertext-firefox/

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Agreed, but JQuery's .text() is really slow: http://jsperf.com/innertext-vs-textcontent-vs-text. Just thought I'd throw that out there for performance-minded individuals. :)